# Software/Ways to help computer run at optimal speed?

Tags: freeze, crash, speed, debug

I have gathered a lot of information already on many different issues-- mainly through websites like these where people seek answers regarding troubleshooting with computers/components. So I figured i'd give it a shot and ask my own question.

I've been trying to figure out for the longest time how to diagnose minor hanging or short periods of time that my computer will freeze (10-30 seconds). Is there any way manually to debug these types of lock ups with helpful software or from my own research without using the Windows Troubleshooting methods? They never seem to help. And also what can I do to fix/modify the way my computer runs so that it will be running at optimal speed? With the exception of buying a solid state drive? Any help is greatly appreaciated. Let me know what info you may need to help debug and I will provide it. I already have programs such as CCleaner, SIW, etc.

I understand this is a very broad question, which I apologize for not rephrasing a little better, I'm just trying to figure out any possible solutions to have an efficiently running system. I have tried almost everything maintenance-wise and have come up empty when debugging when my computer hangs.

Minor Specs: Windows 7 - 64 Bit-- EVGA NVidia GeForce GTX 660 TI 2GB-- AMD-FX 8350-- Asus M5A97 r2.0 (mobo)-- 24 GB Corsair Vegeance RAM PC3-12800-- Hard Drive 1: Seagate 1 TB-- Hard Drive 2: WD 500 GB

Comment: Aside from my below answer an SSD is the best bang for the buck ever.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is usually bad sectors on the hard drive.
get to an Administrative command prompt

chkdsk /R c:
Do you want to do this after reboot?
yes

reboot
make sure chkdsk starts and then find something else to do for 1-2 hours.
Repeat on all hard drives